# Modify ASP CheckBox with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to make a `CheckBox` element inside the table which shows the contents of my database. I'm trying to make it a bit more clickable and nice instead of the default `CheckBox` but since I'm using the ASP `CheckBox` I can't really do a lot with it.

I've looked for different ways and what I've found thus far is:

- Hide the default checkbox and make a CSS one
- Use image button instead and change the image when clicked
- Use a skin file
- Use the CSS checkbox and call the asp code with javascript (my idea)

The problem is that these will be generated for every row and I would call a function checking and identifying (to delete or edit) all the checked records.

What would be the best way to go into this?
Or are there any better ways?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it provides different suggestion for checkbox's css:

[How to style a checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)